# Worksheet Change in Excel [Hiding Particular Rows]

Tags: excel, vba

Here's the screenshot of the file. 
[image]

I am using the following code in VBA to hide few rows automatically with the change of values in a particular cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell   As Range
    Set cell = Range("G1")
    If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("G1").Value > 50 Then
            Rows("12:17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Rows("12:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have changed options to macro enable. The code should work but it is not getting there.

Comment: I would suggest posting a screenshot of your datasheet and explaining what you are after in the post. I don't think many people are going to open a macro-enable excel file from the internet from an unknown source. Also, the `If` condition can just simply be `If Target.Address = "$G$1"`.

Comment: I tried with `If Target.Address = "$G$1"`, still it is not working. If I change the target value over 50 or under 50, nothing happens.

Comment: it works great for me. do you have the code inside the `Worksheet Object Module` for the sheet where the data is (which is where it needs to be) or in a `Standard Module`?

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Check if you have the sheet blocked or something like this.
You could try to put a break point with leftc click in the left margin of the condition row and then change de "G1" value, the program should stop at this line and then if you press F8 you can run it line by line to see how it works.

P.D: In the example image you have a 55 value in the cell, with 55 your code shows the lines. You should put 49 for example to hide them.

Comment: "The code should work but it is not getting there." To get better responses you should detail what your code is actually doing now, and on what line it fails to do what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VBE, tap [ctrl]+G to get to the [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx) and paste this in `Application.EnableEvents = True` then hit enter at the end-of-line.

You code can be appreciably trimmed down to the following.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then
        Rows("12:17").EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(Range("G1").Value <= 50)
    End If
End Sub
```

Make sure that you are in a worksheet code sheet and not the **ThisWorkbook** code sheet or a module code sheet. Right-clicking the worksheet's name tab and choosing **View Code** is the quickest way to make sure you are in the right place.

Comment: It works perfectly now. If I try to use the different worksheet [for example,  change from `Range("G1")` to `Range("Sheet2!A1")`] as the input value, then an error message pops up.

Comment: The **Target** will always be on that worksheet because **Target** is a cell or cells that received a change and triggered the event. It cannot Intersect with a cell on another worksheet. If you want to hide rows on that worksheet when a cell on another worksheet changes, use the Worksheet_Change on the other worksheet or a more global [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event macro.

Comment: If the set cell is in equation format, the code is not working. It only works when we put some values manually.