# Worksheet Row Hiding in Excel VBA when Input value is in Equation format

Tags: excel, vba

This is the extension of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921778/worksheet-change-in-excel-hiding-particular-rows). Here's the screenshot for three cases:

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then
        Rows("5:10").EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(Range("G1").Value <= 10)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have used the answered equation from previous post. It worked when I put the values manually in cell `G1`. When I use formula `G1=H1`, then it stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Worksheet_Calculate() event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()        
        Rows("5:10").EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(Range("G1").Value <= 10)       
End Sub
```

The Worksheet_Change event only deals with cells that are changed directly by the user, while this one fires whenever the sheet calculates.

[image]

[image]